# example/tutorial for using TreeModel+AbstractTreeModel?

Tags: java, swing, treemodel

I have a database containing a hierarchy that I want to display within a JTree.

Is there a good example/tutorial for TreeModel and/or AbstractTreeModel that explains how to implement a custom treemodel? I'm going through a lot of head-scratching and can't seem to find some code out there which is a good starting point.

**edit:** I did find [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JTreeDisplayingtheFileSystemHierarchyUsingtheCustomTreeModel.htm) and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/implementsTreeModeltocreatetreemodel.htm) but they have no helpful comments so I'm not sure what the Firexxx methods are doing and when they get called or when I have to call them.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html) that might help.

**edit:**
There is a simple O'Reilly example [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ch03_19.htm). 
 And this [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data) as well.

Comment: Thanks, but that's about JTree objects using a default built-in TreeModel, and doesn't discuss custom TreeModels at all. (the difference being the former requires a TreeNode to be present for each node in the tree. If you have an infinite or very large dataset, this is not practical w/ that approach.)

Comment: thanks again but that's really really really basic. I need to understand the more subtle issues about event listeners, changing nodes, multithreading issues, etc.

Comment: If I find anything else, I will post it.  I guess at this point, you could start putting your code together and start asking specific questions.  Good Luck.